# ERROR: Service 'mainframe' failed to build: pull access denied for ibmcom/db2express-c, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

Tags: docker, db2

As i am doing docker-compose up --build I get

```
 Creating network "api_default" with the default driver
 Building mainframe
 Step 1/9 : FROM ibmcom/db2express-c
 ERROR: Service 'mainframe' failed to build: pull access denied for ibmcom/db2express-c, repository 
 does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

any suggestion why its not able to build/pull db2 image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compose file is no longer valid because IBM withdrew Db2-express-C some time ago.

It is replaced by Db2-community edition.

Change your Dockerfile(s) or compose-file(s) to pull instead `ibmcom/db2`

And follow the instructions [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2).